# ng2-translate - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am going to start to use ng-translate in my project but I am getting an error.

Right now, I have just added it to my *app.module.ts* and it is already failing.

My **code** is the following:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
            deps: [Http]
        })
```

and the **error**:

```
: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Http'.
```

I am reading this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate)

Comment: You don't import `Http`: `import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `ngx-translate`. `ng2-translate` is deprecated.

Secondly, even if you want to go on with `ng2-translate` you need to import `Http`:

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Also depending on the version of Angular he may want to use `HttpClient` which is also what ngx-translate currently documents using.

Comment: As long as `HttpClientModule` is listed in `imports` I assume it is already clear :D

Comment: My fault. I totally forgot that. And thank you for recommending "ngx-translate". I ll mark the answer as correct in 10 minutes. Sorry for this stupid question.